# conditional conditions in Java

Tags: java, eval, lazy-evaluation

I have:

```
boolean cond=false;
if(!gto)
  cond=(in-Math.pow(base, pot)<0);
else
  cond=(in-Math.pow(base, pot)>=0);
while(cond)//Pos1
...
```

This work not in the desired way, because `pot` is changed within the while-loop.
Of coure I could write a boolean-valued method, but I wonder, if there is a way to force Java to evaluate `cond` just when reaching Pos1?

Comment: write that mentioned method.

Comment: Does the value of `gto` change in the loop as well?

Comment: Please show us your whole code, otherwise we could miss something...

Comment: @Chrusha K Rool: no

Comment: @Overblade: Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while((in-Math.pow(base,pot<0&&!gto)||(in-Math.pow(base, pot)>=0&&gto))){
//do sth
}
```

is this what you want?

Comment: This is a lazy way btw. I dont recommend this for big projects

Answer (score 0):

For cleanliness and maintainability, use a method, assuming you have Java 8 available, you could also use a lambda predicate as shown below:

```
Predicate<Boolean> checkCondition = (boolean gto) -> {
    double someCalculationResult = in - Math.pow(base, pot);
    if (!gto) {
        return someCalculationResult < 0;
    }
    return someCalculationResult >= 0;
}

while (checkCondition(gto)) {
    ... 
}
```

Or inline the condition (see answer by @kleopi) if this is some write and forget about it code.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `gto` does not change in the loop and the loop body is not complex, then you could just write two separate loops for the individual cases:

```
if ( gto ) {
    while ( in - Math.pow(base, pot) >= 0 ) {
      // Do stuff
    }
} else {
    while ( in - Math.pow(base, pot) < 0 ) {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

If possible, you could then also move the loop body into a separate method and call it from both loops.